# How to customize date format when creating excel cells through javascript (activexobject)?

Tags: javascript, excel, date, activex, format

I'm trying to convert an HTML table to Excel in Javascript using new `ActiveXObject("Excel.application")`. Bascially I loop through table cells and insert the value to the corresponding cell in excel:

```
//for each table cell
oSheet.Cells(x,y).value = cell.innerText;
```

The problem is that when the cell is in date format of 'dd-mm-yyyy' (e.g. 10-09-2008), excel would read as 'mm-dd-yyyy' (i.e. 09 Oct 2008). I tried to specify `NumberFormat` like:

```
oSheet.Cells(x,y).NumberFormat = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
```

But, it has no effect. It seems that this only affect how excel **display the value, not parse**. My only solution now is to swap the date like:

```
var txt = cell.innerText;
if(/^(\d\d)-(\d\d)-\d\d\d\d$/.test(txt)) txt = txt.replace(/^(\d\d)-(\d\d)/,'$2-$1');
```

But, I'm worrying that it is not generic and a differnt machine setting would fail this.

Is there a way to specific how excel **parse** the input value?

Comment: What is the Windows locale of the PC?

Answer (score 0):

In Vbscript, we use to resolve this by

```
    If IsDate ( Cell.Value ) Then
         Cell.Value = DateValue ( Cell.Value )
    End If
```

Maybe, In java script also you need to play with same approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid Excel's date parsing by entering the data using its native 'serial' date format. e.g '22nd Dec 08' is 39804 as an Excel serial date. (See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) for a good explanation of these)

Then format the cell as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

1. determine what culture-neutral date formats excel supports
2. use javascript to parse your date string and output in the an appropriate format

I don't know what formats excel supports but you'd want something like [.net's round trip or sortable formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), where it will always be read consistently.

for #2, if you can trust javascript to construct an appropriate date from whatever string you feed it that's fine. if you're not sure about that you might look at a library like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) where you can be more specific about what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
oSheet.Cells(x,y).NumberFormat = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
```

set this:

```
oSheet.Cells(x,y).NumberFormat = 14;
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried your code but at end of the process, I re-applied format to the columns containing dates. It works fine, no matter what local language you have configurated yor machine.

Being my excel object defined as 'template', as soon as I got it data filled, I applied (just for example):

```
template.ActiveSheet.Range("D10:F99").NumberFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy;@";
```

best regards

Comment: Your answer is about displaying those values, while the question is how to tell Excel to parse the values differently.