# HTML to Excel: Data format changes

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I have the following code to export HTML tables to Excel:

```
function exportToExcel(tableID)
{
    var detailsTable= document.getElementById(tableID);
    var oExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add;
    var oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1);
    for (var y=0;y<detailsTable.rows.length;y++)
    {
        for (var x=0;x<detailsTable.rows(y).cells.length;x++)
        {
            oSheet.Cells(y+1,x+1)= detailsTable.rows(y).cells(x).innerText;
        }
    }

    oExcel.Visible = true;
    oExcel.UserControl = true;
    oExcel.Columns.AutoFit();
    oExcel.Rows.Autofit();
}
```

The export works but Excel is changing the dates in some cases. Instead of DD/MM/YYYY it changes to MM/DD/YYYY.

> For example: In HTML the date is 29/05/2014 (DD/MM/YYYY), in Excel the date is 29/05/2014 (DD/MM/YYYY). In HTML the date is 02/07/2014 (DD/MM/YYYY) in Excel the date is 07/02/2014 (MM/DD/YYYY), this last case is wrong.

Tried to format the javascript date without lucky to:

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Tried to use NumberFormat without lucky:

```
oExcel.Cells(y+1,x+1).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
```

Tried to use the style in the TD without lucky:

```
style="mso-number-format:"dd\/mm\/yyyy"
```

**UPDATE:**

Adding (as a test):

```
oSheet.Cells(y+1,x+1).NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
```

Inside the second `for`, actually format the date. As I can see the date is already wrong in this point. I mean, in the table it shows 07/11/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy) and in the export it shows 11/07/2014 (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: can you try `oExcel.Cells(y+1,x+1).NumberFormat = 14;` and see if that works?

Comment: Well, it insert "14" in the cell, formating the date to dd/mm/yyyy bring the result as if mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: There was already a similar Question, see: [How to customize date format when creating excel cells through javascript (activexobject)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/380100/4137828)

Answer (score 1):

[Check this solution using XLSX library.](https://theflowingfact.blogspot.com/2020/05/nodejsangular-sheetjs-js-xlsx-library.html)
Also apart from date format, it also roundoffs the number. These 2 issues are fixed by this solution.

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
<table class="table " #table1>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name
<th>Dob(DD/MM/YYYY)
<th>Id
<th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of colors;index as i">
<td [style.color]="colors[i]">
{{item.name}}
</td>
<td t='s' [style.color]="colors[i]">//This t='s' solves the issue.
{{item.dob}}
</td>
<td t='s' [style.color]="colors[i]">
<!-- This is most important t='s' -->
{{item.id}}
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" (click)="importTable2()">Export Table Two</button>
</div>
```

TS code:

```js
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('table') table: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('table1') table1: ElementRef;


  colors = [{
      name: 'Rubecaa',
      dob: '11/10/1998',
      id: '1000100020202010101AB'
    },
    {
      name: 'Zena',
      dob: '17/11/1998',
      id: '10001000202020101010'
    } //Id is string but sometimes it may contains only  number.
  ];



  importTable2() {
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table1.nativeElement);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'Table2.xlsx');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is different approach I use to convert HTML tables to CSV and excel.Its a platform independent i.e. works also when ActiveXObject not available.

Your table code should have following structure. Note that it just assigns class name as list to rows which you want in Excel file.

```js
$u("#btnXLS").click(function() {

  var xls = jQuery(".list").map(function(a, i) {
    return $u.trim($u(this).text()).split(/\s*\n\s*/).join("\t");
  }).toArray().join("\r\n");
  download(xls, "All_Data.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");

});

// download() function
function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
  var D = document,
    a = D.createElement("a");
  var Data = "Date :-" + Date();
  Data += "\n\n" + strData;
  strData = Data;
  strFileName = strFileName.substr(0, strFileName.indexOf('.'));
  strFileName += Date();
  if (strMimeType.indexOf("text/csv") >= 0)
    strFileName += ".csv";
  else
    strFileName += ".xls";
  strMimeType = strMimeType || "application/octet-stream";
  if (window.MSBlobBuilder) { //IE10+ routine
    var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
    bb.append(strData);
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
  } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */
  if ('download' in a) { //html5 A[download]
    if (!window.URL) {
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([strData]));

    } else {
      a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + encodeURIComponent(strData);
    }

    a.setAttribute("download", strFileName);
    a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
    D.body.appendChild(a);
    setTimeout(function() {
      a.click();
      D.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 66);
    return true;
  } /* end if('download' in a) */
  //do iframe dataURL download (old ch+FF):
  var f = D.createElement("iframe");
  D.body.appendChild(f);
  f.src = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + encodeURIComponent(strData);

  setTimeout(function() {
    D.body.removeChild(f);
  }, 333);
  return true;
} /* end download() */
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="list">
      <th>Column Header</th>
      <th>Column Header</th>
      <th>Column Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="list">
      <td>11</td>
      <td style="background: #33cc00;">11</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="list odd">
      <td>22</td>
      <td style="background: #33cc00;">22</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gonna try this later. I was about to drop the code I am using because it works only on IE. And I was about to search for an independent browser solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work in IE11, in Firefox it download the file, but in excel it alert the user that the file is different. Opening the file, all the data is in the first column. The solution I was using is good because it opens the excel, with the data without warning the user. Can we have your solution with the same behavior? Thanks

Comment: if you can post sample table code then i will try something else

Comment: the table code has the same structure you posted above. Thanks. My main problem is with date. I have 10/05/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy) and in excel it shows as mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but I have a web application that displays data in a nicely formatted table, and if they want it in excel, I just write the exact same data to a new page, but change the headers to mime type excel and it works beautifully!  Gets the formatting, color, etc.  Displays headers nicely.  Just a thought.